# Does not using node_save for updating nodes impact SEO for our site

Tags: nodes

We changed our node updation process from using node_save() to manually updating the nodes via db queries.

What dramatic change we have seen is that number of people coming to us via seo has dropped significantly after this change.

Does not using node_save impacts the SEO in any way for example :
1) It impacts the site map which we are not doing manually.
2) It updates a particular field important for SEO which we are not doing
3) Any thing extra

**EDIT:** On further checking the sitemap we have found that Last Modified date is not getting changed in the xml sitemap for the nodes that are updated using the manual process.

Comment: Node_save updates edit timestamp. If your theme feeds "edited xx.xx.xxx" to Google and other search engines, then proper Drupal edit might mark your content as "fresher". And so on. Look at your theme and tell what meta-information you made available - then we'll be able to tell what is changed by node_save() and gauge it's SEO impact. Now we can only guess.

Comment: On further checking the sitemap we have found that Last Modified date is not getting changed in the xml sitemap for the nodes that are updated using the manual process.

Comment: Because you are not updating nodes "manually" - you're executing a SQL query. The rest of the application has no idea. Use the API, its there for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never manipulate entities directly in the database - even if you're 100% sure you've covered everything that core needs to do when an entity is saved, any number of contrib modules you have installed could need to process things too. How that affects your site is completely down to what you have installed, and how you have that set up.

One of the bigger problems you'll have is that the correct field/entity caches won't be cleared, leaving your database and front end in a potentially inconsistent state. This could include stale meta tags, page content, etc, etc.

I can't comment specifically on your SEO, but certainly if you bypass the proper way of saving/updating data, you shouldn't be surprised to see all sorts of problems arise.

Comment: On further checking the sitemap we have found that Last Modified date is not getting changed in the xml sitemap for the nodes that are updated using the manual process.

Comment: Yep that proves my point perfectly - you're not giving the xmlsitemap contrib module the chance to make the changes it needs to. Multiply that by how many contrib modules you have installed, and you start to get an idea of the problems you're giving yourself by directly manipulating that data

Comment: Can it be done manually or should i go back to node_save. (The main purpose of not using node_save() was because it was taking too much time to update nodes and we wanted the updation to be fast for our site relevancy)

Comment: Theoretically it can be done manually, but I wouldn't advise it. The only way to do it reliably would be to go through every implementation of `hook_node_update()`, `hook_field_attach_update()` etc in your site, and reproduce the necessary logic in raw SQL. Not a lot of fun really...

Comment: @user2129794 as Clive says, possible. But what's the point of using Content Management System if you don't want to use it to manage your content? ;)